# ASP.NET Filter Access Database Gridview with Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, webforms

I am trying to filter a gridview with a dropdownlist. My gridview and dropdownlist are being populated by an Access database. What I want is when a supplier is selected from the dropdownlist it will filter the gridview of products to those with that supplierid.

I am able to populate the dropdownlist and gridview, but when I select a Supplier nothing happens.

I tried adding FilterExpression="SupplierID Like '{0}%'", but then the page errors out with Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String

Here is my code.

```
<form id="form" runat="server" style="margin:0 auto;">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="Supplier" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/Hovden Oil Pricing.accdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Supplier], [ID] FROM [Suppliers] ORDER BY [Supplier]">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">

    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SupplierID" HeaderText="SupplierID" 
            SortExpression="SupplierID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product Number" HeaderText="Product Number" 
            SortExpression="Product Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product Name" HeaderText="Product Name" 
            SortExpression="Product Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product Type" HeaderText="Product Type" 
            SortExpression="Product Type" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Bulked" HeaderText="Bulked" 
            SortExpression="Bulked" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UOM" HeaderText="UOM" SortExpression="UOM" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Multiple" HeaderText="Multiple" 
            SortExpression="Multiple" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="$/GAL" HeaderText="$/GAL" SortExpression="$/GAL" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="$/UNIT" HeaderText="$/UNIT" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="$/UNIT" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TypeID" HeaderText="TypeID" 
            SortExpression="TypeID" />
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/Hovden Oil Pricing.accdb" SelectCommand="SELECT [Supplier Products].SupplierID, Products.[Product Number], Products.[Product Name], [Product Types].[Product Type], Products.Bulked, Products.UOM, Products.Multiple, [Bulk Prices].Volume AS [$/GAL], [$/GAL]*[Multiple] AS [$/UNIT], [Product Types].TypeID
    FROM [Product Types] INNER JOIN ((Products INNER JOIN [Supplier Products] ON Products.[Product Number] = [Supplier Products].[Product Number]) INNER JOIN [Bulk Prices] ON (Products.[Product Number] = [Bulk Prices].[Product Number]) AND (Products.[Product Number] = [Bulk Prices].[Product Number])) ON [Product Types].TypeID = Products.[Product Type]
    WHERE (Products.Bulked)=Yes
    ORDER BY Products.[Product Name];" FilterExpression="SupplierID Like '{0}%'">
    <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="SupplierID" ControlID="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </FilterParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
</form>
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: this is not asp.net mvc ! please edit your tags.

Comment: MVC is what I'm using for this website. Should I still remove the tag?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC does not have any server controls like what you have in the Question. Those are of Web forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple really, you are trying to compare an int(SupplierID) to a wild card string value, that's why you're getting the above error.

Simply convert the SupplierID to a string and it will work:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/Hovden Oil Pricing.accdb" SelectCommand="SELECT [Supplier Products].SupplierID, Products.[Product Number], Products.[Product Name], [Product Types].[Product Type], Products.Bulked, Products.UOM, Products.Multiple, [Bulk Prices].Volume AS [$/GAL], [$/GAL]*[Multiple] AS [$/UNIT], [Product Types].TypeID
    FROM [Product Types] INNER JOIN ((Products INNER JOIN [Supplier Products] ON Products.[Product Number] = [Supplier Products].[Product Number]) INNER JOIN [Bulk Prices] ON (Products.[Product Number] = [Bulk Prices].[Product Number]) AND (Products.[Product Number] = [Bulk Prices].[Product Number])) ON [Product Types].TypeID = Products.[Product Type]
    WHERE (Products.Bulked)=Yes
    ORDER BY Products.[Product Name];" FilterExpression="Convert(SupplierID , 'System.String') LIKE '{0}%'">
    <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="SupplierID" ControlID="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </FilterParameters>
```

Comment: When I select a Supplier from the dropdownlist it reloads the page and resets the dropdownlist and gridview. Doesn't filter anything.

Comment: I take that back, I think it is filtering. It is filtering with the default value in the dropdownlist. But when I select different supplier it reloads page and resets dropdownlist back to the default value keeping the gridview the same.

Comment: I'm glad that at least it's binding now,that's a step forward.It's hard to tell exactly why it keeps being reset to the default value because I don't have access to your project.The best I can suggest is to test your query out in Access and make sure that it's 100 and just play around with the code.Look at the example in the link I've provided and try figure out how your code differs to that

Comment: Could the AutoPostBack be refreshing the page?

Comment: Not could,it IS refreshing the page and when the page is reconstructed on the server it should take the selected value and use it in the AccessDataSource query and in turn that will update the gridview.You need to find out why that's not happening in your case

Comment: Do I need if IsPostBack in my controller?

Comment: Do you have any bindings in code behind?if not then you don't need it to.to me it looks like all your databinding is in design view or am i wrong?

Comment: I agree it's all in my view. Just can't figure out why it's happening. I changed the gridview to a simple table rather than a query; SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Supplier Products] WHERE SupplierId=@SupplierID" but it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: If you have Google docs post your project on there and share a link with me and I'll try figure out what's going wrong

Comment: Do you want the whole project?

Comment: here's the link. It includes my site and the database. On the home page there is a link called Pricing below welcome. Let me know what you find. https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0BxX6CIDigV64NmxzeU5kS2xpVjQ/edit

Comment: Sorry. Try it now https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0BxX6CIDigV64NmxzeU5kS2xpVjQ/edit